# loop data into object javascript and returning the value

Tags: javascript

i try loop data into empty object but it turns out the data after i console.log the data only return one object wher, can someone tell me where i did wrong here

```
const data_warehouse = forms.map((item) => {
        item.answer.map((data) => {
          let data_fix = {};
          Object.keys(data.answers).map((key) => {
            return (data_fix = {
              [key.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase()]: data.answers[key],
            });
          });
          console.log(data_fix);
        });
      });
```

here is the data from mongoDB:

```
"forms": [
        {
            "_id": "Quality",
            "title": "Quality",
            "answer": [
                {
                    "username": "Jansenstan24@gmail.coms",
                    "date": "2022-10-25",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "Text": "john@dose.com",
                        "Email": "john@nabatisnack.com",
                        "Plant": "Cica"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "username": "adam@wegodev.com",
                    "date": "2022-10-25",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "Email": "john@dose.coms",
                        "Plant": "Ranca",
                        "Text Doang": "12"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "username": "jansenstan24@gmail.com",
                    "date": "2022-10-31",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "Text": "john@nabatisnack.com",
                        "Email": "john@dose.com",
                        "Plant": "Cica"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

i try to redesign the key on field "answers" to change all the specials characters into underscore, but its only returning one data after i loop it into map function:

```
{ plant: 'Cica' }
{ text_doang: '12' }
{ plant: 'Cica' }
```

my expected result should be like this,it will return the same format but only cleanup the special characters from the key on field "answers":

```
 [
        {
            "_id": "Quality",
            "title": "Quality",
            "answer": [
                {
                    "username": "Jansenstan24@gmail.coms",
                    "date": "2022-10-25",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "text": "john@dose.com",
                        "email": "john@nabatisnack.com",
                        "plant": "Cica"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "username": "adam@wegodev.com",
                    "date": "2022-10-25",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "email": "john@dose.coms",
                        "plant": "Ranca",
                        "text_doang": "12"
                    }
                },...etc]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```js
var forms=[
        {
            "_id": "Quality",
            "title": "Quality",
            "answer": [
                {
                    "username": "Jansenstan24@gmail.coms",
                    "date": "2022-10-25",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "Text": "john@dose.com",
                        "Email": "john@nabatisnack.com",
                        "Plant": "Cica"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "username": "adam@wegodev.com",
                    "date": "2022-10-25",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "Email": "john@dose.coms",
                        "Plant": "Ranca",
                        "Text Doang": "12"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "username": "jansenstan24@gmail.com",
                    "date": "2022-10-31",
                    "formId": "6357921d49de88bb7fffcfe4",
                    "answers": {
                        "Text": "john@nabatisnack.com",
                        "Email": "john@dose.com",
                        "Plant": "Cica"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
  var newData=  forms.map((item) => {
        var mappedAns=item.answer.map((data) => {
          let data_fix = {};
          Object.keys(data.answers).forEach((key) => {
            data_fix[key.replace(/ /g, "_").toLowerCase()]= data.answers[key];
          });
          return {...data,answers:data_fix};
        });
        return {...item,answer:mappedAns}
      });
      
 console.log(newData);
```

Comment: can you explain the logic to me?...

Comment: ```...``` is spread syntax you can read more about this here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax